# Deploying Firebase functions with a shared package shows errors about conflicting lockfiles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working off a monorepo with folders

```
/front
/back
/shared
```

I am trying to deploy my backend functions to Firebase.

I can run them on Firebase emulator nicely locally. However, when trying to deploy them online, I am faced with this error:

```
...
i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged $PROJECT_PATH/MYPROJECT/back/functions (2.39 MB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 18 function api(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @MYPROJECT/shared@1.0.0 does not satisfy @MYPROJECT/shared@
npm ERR! Missing: @MYPROJECT/shared@ from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
...
```

In back/functions/package.json, I have this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@MYPROJECT/shared": "file:../../shared",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
    "got": "^11.8.2",
    "openai": "^2.0.5",
    "serialize-error": "^11.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.4",
    "vitest": "^0.28.3"
  },
```

And in shared/package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.8.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.28.3",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.4",
    "vitest": "^0.28.3"
  }
}
```

In back/firebase.json I have this:

```
{
  "source": "functions",
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build"
  }
}
```

I tried reinstalling everything like this:

```
cd $PROJECT_PATH/MYPROJECT/shared
rm -r node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm cache clean --force
cd $PROJECT_PATH/MYPROJECT/back/functions
rm -r node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm cache clean --force
npm install
cd $PROJECT_PATH/MYPROJECT/shared
npm install
cd $PROJECT_PATH/MYPROJECT/back/
firebase functions:delete api; firebase deploy --only functions
```

But I still get the same error.

Any other suggestions on what could be the issue?

Comment: The dependencies listed in your `back/functions/package.json` file and the lockfile made by npm 
during installation are at conflict with one another.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a conflict, I just don't know how to fix it. It seems to somehow relate to how npm and firebase handles the situation. Not a fix, but I found a workaround and added it here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4822#issuecomment-1435501405

Comment: Update the lockfile: You can try running npm install in the back/functions directory to update the lockfile to reflect the correct versions of the shared package and its dependencies.